# What memory access architecture has an i9 processor?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture, numa, memory-access

What *memory access architecture* has and **i9 processor** (UMA ,NUMA OR CC-NUMA)?

Is it different from previous processors like **i7**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel is using NUMA in its new Skylake chips, but with a new (mesh) topology that defeats some of the negative effects of NUMA.

[image: Mesh topology]

Intel is abandoning the ring topology it's used to connect CPU cores in its many-core CPUs for several generations. In place of its ring, the company is introducing a new mesh interconnect topology that promises several improvements. First off, Intel says its mesh interconnect delivers ***lower latency and higher bandwidth than the ring bus***, all while operating at a lower frequency and voltage. Those last two characteristics are important, because they should result in less power consumption from the interconnect portion of the chip as it scales up.
***The mesh topology in Skylake-X should make headaches from the non-uniform distribution and access latencies of resources among rings a thing of the past***.

Sources:
https://www.anandtech.com/show/11550/the-intel-skylakex-review-core-i9-7900x-i7-7820x-and-i7-7800x-tested/5

http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/forum/hardware-canucks-reviews/76102-intel-i9-7980xe-i9-7960x-performance-review-3.html